# Spring Security Issue creating bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

With Spring Security I'm trying to create the following authentication verification using Spring.

```
@Service("LoginUserDetailsServiceImpl")
public class LoginUserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService  {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(UserDetailsService.class);

    @Autowired
    private CustomerDao customerDao;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String  email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        logger.info("Customer DAO Email:" +email);
        Customer customer = customerDao.getCustomer(email);
        logger.info("Customer DAO Email:" +customer.getEmail());        
        Roles role = customer.getRole();
        logger.info("Customer DAO Role:" + role.getRoles());
        MyUserPrincipalimpl principal = new MyUserPrincipalimpl(customer);


        logger.info("customerUserDetails DAO:" +principal);
           if (customer == null) {
                throw new UsernameNotFoundException(email);
            }


           return principal;
        }

}
```

Which produces the following error

```
5:56,638  WARN XmlWebApplicationContext:487 - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'LoginUserDetailsServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.emusicstore.dao.CustomerDao com.emusicstore.serviceImpl.LoginUserDetailsServiceImpl.customerDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.emusicstore.dao.CustomerDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
```

I've found if I comment out the following

```
<bean id="LoginUserDetailsServiceImpl" class="com.emusicstore.serviceImpl.LoginUserDetailsServiceImpl"/>
```

from my application-security.xml the above error is not produced. Also my junit test will execute with no issue.

```
@Autowired
    CustomerDao customerDao;

    @Test
    public void LoginService() {
        String email="customeremail";
        logger.info("Customer DAO Email:" +email);
        Customer customer = customerDao.getCustomer(email);
        logger.info("Customer DAO Email:" +customer.getEmail());        
        Roles role = customer.getRole();
        logger.info("Customer DAO Role:" + role.getRoles());

    }
```

Repo

```
@Repository

    public class CustomerDaoImp implements CustomerDao {

        private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CustomerDaoImp.class);

        @Autowired
        SessionFactory sessionFactory;
```

Application-security.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:webflow-config="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config"
    xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">


<!-- <bean id="LoginUserDetailsServiceImpl" class="com.emusicstore.serviceImpl.LoginUserDetailsServiceImpl"/>-->

    <security:http auto-config="true"  use-expressions="true">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/login_test" access="permitAll" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/logout" access="permitAll" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/accessdenied" access="permitAll" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/productList" access="permitAll" />
<!--         <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll" /> -->
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/shoppingCart/checkOut" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
        <security:form-login login-page="/login_test" login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check" authentication-failure-url="/accessdenied" 
        />
        <security:logout logout-success-url="/logout" />
    </security:http> 


 <!--  <security:authentication-manager>-
        <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="LoginUserDetailsServiceImpl"/>
    </security:authentication-manager> -->

    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider>
            <security:user-service>
                <security:user name="lokesh" password="password" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            </security:user-service>
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>


    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName"
            value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="t3l3com" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>com.emusicstore</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>


    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="multipartResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="1024000" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Spring-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">



    <mvc:annotation-driven></mvc:annotation-driven>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.emusicstore"></context:component-scan>


    <bean id="viewresolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">

        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"></property>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>

    </bean>

    <bean id="multipartResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">

        <!-- setting maximum upload size -->
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="10000000" />

    </bean>

    <mvc:resources location="/WEB-INF/resource/" mapping="/resource/**"></mvc:resources>

     <tx:annotation-driven />


</beans>
```

I'm not sure where exactly the issue is but I'm guessing it is in how the bean is configured in the xml. Should I reference the customerDao bean when in my xml file? I would have thought the @Autowired annotation would have resolved this however?

**UPDATE**
If I update the application-security to add a new Customer Dao bean a new error message is thrown.

```
<bean id="LoginUserDetailsServiceImpl" class="com.emusicstore.serviceImpl.LoginUserDetailsServiceImpl"/>
<bean id="CustomerDao" class="com.emusicstore.daoImpl.CustomerDaoImp"/>
```

I get the following error `'org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.emusicstore.dao.CustomerDao] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: customerDaoImp,CustomerDao'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is a `CustomerDao` instance can't be found by Spring. Either it's failed to instantiate somewhere higher up in your logs, or likely it hasn't been defined in a way that it can be instantiated and made available for injection by Spring Framework.

If you're using XML based dependency injection then defined `CustomerDao` instance with id `customerDao` in your XML similar to how `LoginUserDetailsServiceImpl` is defined.

Or if you're using annotation based dependency injection then add the appropriate stereotype annotation (`@Component`, `@Repository` etc) to the `CustomerDao` so Spring IoC knows to instantiate it and make is available for dependency injection.

Comment: Agreed but my question is it why is not been instantiated for 'LoginUserDetailsServiceImpl'  but it is for my junit test. The 'CustomerDao'  should be instantiated by my 'spring-servlet.xml' and does do this for my junit, however when I use the  'LoginUserDetailsServiceImpl' bean it cannot instatiate the same 'CustomerDao'

Comment: Smells to me like unit tests are probably using annotation based, while your app at runtime is using xml based. Your beans are annotated correctly(I see now) and probably explains why tests work. If you comment `LoginUserDetailsServiceImpl` out it will start up as it's now not looking for `customerDao` because it's probably not instantiating `LoginUserDetailsServiceImpl` at all. I suspect it will work if you add `customerDao` to your XML or define it with `@Bean` programatically.

Comment: I've updated my question as per your comments this throws a new error which is shown in error message.

Comment: Right, that message `expected single matching bean but found 2: customerDaoImp,CustomerDao'` implies both xml and annotation based is in the mix. It's now complaining that two of the same types are being created. So if you remove the xml one and then update the variable `CustomerDao customerDao;` in `LoginUserDetailsServiceImpl` to `CustomerDao customerDaoImpl;` it should find the first one being created, which was there the whole time. The naming is important, it's essentially the bean id. Alternatively you could change the `@Repository` annotation to to be `@Repository("customerDao")`.

Comment: Second option is probably tidier, hopefully that works for your setup.

Comment: I've found removing the @Repository will remove the issue I'm having and adding the bean to the XML. If I was to guess there is an issue as I think the application-servlet.xml is initiates the 'LoginUserDetailsServiceImpl' but as the spring-servlet.xml has not instantiated its objects yet the CustomerDao bean does not exist.  I will except the answer as it has help improve my debugging. Although I would not consider my issue fixed.